# Unable to publish SMS to endpoints using AWS SNS http request(Could not find operation Publish for version 2010-03-31)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to send  SMS to endpoints the things i did ,

Created topic,subscriber through SNS console,

when i hit the following url i am geting ,

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSFault/2005-15-09">
 <Error>
     <Type>Sender</Type>
     <Code>InvalidAction</Code>
      <Message>Could not find operation Publish  for version 2010-03-31</Message>
 </Error>
<RequestId>9097b3ca-a049-509a-9810-e23660d342ef</RequestId>
```

And I am using Following get Request which is provided in AWS SNS Documentation

```
 http://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ ?Subject=My%20first%20message
         &TopicArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789456:ABC
         &Message=Hello%20world%21 &Action=Publish &SignatureVersion=2
         &SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256 &Timestamp=2017-08-03T06%3A20%3A00.000Z
         &AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
         &Signature=9GZysQ4Jpnz%2BHklqM7VFTvEcjR2LIUtn6jW47054xxE%3D
```

How can i send sms through above url.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was because of a carriage return in the url params. Very confusing error actually.

So my advice is to review the request url for spaces or invisible (control) characters.